# Forms divided into tabs in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, forms, tabs, wicket

I'm working on a project, that requires forms on page to be divided and put into separate tabs. Apache Wicket have very nice and simple way to do tabs by itself (TabbedPanel class), but my concern is, that this solution rely on AJAX for loading the content of the panels, hence the only one part of the form would be submitted after user presses "Submit" button.

I found a solution for simple CSS/JS tabs (http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/), but I feel uneasy to use third party solution, and it is complicating my project (also, I'm not sure about the license).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several impls of TabbedPanel with JQuery which are completely JS/CSS based.
See wicketstuff's jquery integration project and WiQuery project.

Comment: Thank you for a tip, but I went with non-jQuery based CSS/JS solution. Still, your tip about integration of jQuery with Wicket is valuable for my future projects. :)

Answer (score 1):

The default TabbedPanel doesn't use AJAX. To use Ajax there is a own implementation (AjaxTabbedPanel).

Comment: But this still means that the components on the different tabs will be submitted in different requests.

Comment: @McGregor - exactly! - I tried both AjaxTabbedPanel and TabbedPanel. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a wizard to me. Since wicket provides a [wizard component](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/wizard) to handle this kind of use case this might be a good point to look. Since I've not yet used this component I don't know how far it can be taken to display tabs but if it can't, it might at least give you the idea on how to build your own with tabs.

Comment: wizard may be worth looking upon, but there is explicit requirement to do this in tabs.

Comment: @DoktorNo Tabs should be easily implemented by overriding protected `Component newButtonBar(final String id)` from Wizard and supplying an own implementation of `org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard.IDefaultButtonProvider` that builds your tabs (and maybe hides the other buttons originally found in wizards).

Comment: Sounds good, but "real" tabs allows user to quickly go to specific part of the form, without the need of going through other panels, like in wizard.

Comment: @DoktorNo Thats why you should implement your own ButtonBar with all the Buttons to your tabs

Comment: I tried CSS/JS solution from my link in my question, and so far it is the most feasible one. No extra Java coding is needed, this is just what I need.